# How to use Stockfish for the review feature on Chess com?

Tags: engines, software, online-chess

I really like the "Review" feature in Chess com, where there is a "virtual coach" explaining why a particular move is better than the other. But it requires a paid membership for more than one review per day. I don't see something similar when I try to analyze the game using Stockfish alone. Could someone suggest how I could download any free/open source program that does the same?

Comment: The question appears to be from a bot account

Answer (score 2):

After completing a game you can select options and choose 'self analysis' which is free and unlimited. It uses stockfish to give you a similar analysis without the words.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am having difficulty as to why stockfish recommends a particular move when I see it on Lichess or any site. The "virtual coach" makes it much easier for me to understand why it was a good/bad/blunder move. I was looking for some tool which I could download that could give me unlimited "virtual coach" advise

Answer (score 1):

[**Lichess**](https://lichess.org/) has a free game review feature that employs Stockfish.

1. After a game, you can analyze the game and learn from your mistakes.
2. You can store games in the Study feature and request a computer analysis.
3. You can import a game and request a computer analysis. For example, you can see the computer analysis for the famous [Ivanchuk-Kasparov (Linares, 1991) game](https://lichess.org/OvXnk9kZ#0) with evaluations on each move, [annotations](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/41396/26335) (e.g., inaccuracies, mistakes, and blunders), and [accuracy scores](https://lichess.org/page/accuracy).

Granted, this doesn't have the same "coach" [interface as Chess.com](https://support.chess.com/article/364-how-does-the-game-report-analysis-work), but it is free.

[image: Screenshot of part of the Lichess game analysis for the Ivanchuk-Kasparov (Linares, 1991) game]

[**DecodeChess**](https://decodechess.com/) claims to "*explain the why behind chess moves*" but I am not familiar with its functionality in detail. Since there is a pricing page, I imagine the free version is limited.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am having difficulty as to why stockfish recommends a particular move when I see it on Lichess or any site. The "virtual coach" makes it much easier for me to understand why it was a good/bad/blunder move. I was looking for some tool which I could download that could give me unlimited "virtual coach" advise

Comment: @user3760100 I get that but I'm not sure what you want currently exists as specified. I could only answer with what I know exists.  Good luck!